# Adding Value To Combobox With FormControl In Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

**UPDATE**

```
 <select (blur)="stateValidate('State *Required', 'State Name')" class="form-control" id="state_address" formControlName="state_address">
                      <option *ngFor="let state of states">{{state}}</option>
```

I have a form and I am pre filling in the values based on data I have on the user in the database. I am able to add all the values to the form like this,

```
city_address: new FormControl(this.contractData.city_address, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Zñáéíóúü' ]{1,30}$")
      ]),
```

But when I try to add the state to the combobox, it does not provide the value.

```
// this does not work.
    state_address: new FormControl(this.contractData.state_address, [
    Validators.required
  ]),
```

Why does this behavior happen and what is the proper way to add a value to a combobox based on the users data stored in the database?

**HTML**

```
 <form [formGroup]="contractForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="saveContract(contractForm.value, contractForm.valid)" (window:resize)="beResponsive()">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <div class="card card-inverse card-success">
            <div class="card-header">
              <strong>Personal Information</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <!-- Start Phone Section -->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                  <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                  </span>

                    <input (blur)="cityValidate('City *Required', 'City Name')" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter city name" id="city_address" formControlName="city_address">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                  <label for="state_address">State</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-street-view"></i>
                  </span>
```

**FORMGROUP**

```
  this.contractForm = new FormGroup({
      signatureField1 : new FormControl('',Validators.required ),
      email : new FormControl(this.contractData.email,Validators.required ),
      first_name: new FormControl(this.contractData.first_name,[
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Zñáéíóúü']{1,30}$")
      ]),
      middle_name: new FormControl(this.contractData.middle_name,[
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Zñáéíóúü']{1,30}$")
      ]),
      last_name: new FormControl(this.contractData.last_name,[
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Zñáéíóúü']{1,30}$")
      ]),
      employer: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Zñáéíóúü' ]{1,30}$")
      ]),
      dob : new FormControl (this.contractData.dob, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("[1][9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]|[2][0][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]")
      ]),
      client_ss: new FormControl(this.contractData.client_ss, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
      ]),
      phone: new FormControl(this.contractData.phone, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"),
      ]),
      work_phone: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"),
      ]),
      fax_phone: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"),
      ]),
      street_address: new FormControl (this.contractData.street_address, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("^[0-9]+ .+$")
      ]),
      city_address: new FormControl(this.contractData.city_address, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Zñáéíóúü' ]{1,30}$")
      ]),
      state_address: new FormControl(this.contractData.state_address, [
        Validators.required
      ]),
      zip_address: new FormControl(this.contractData.zip_address, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
      ]),
      client_dl: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required
      ]),
      dl_state: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required
      ]),
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that `this.contractData.state_address` is not null or empty?

Comment: Yes. I checked it and it indeed outputs texas when I do {{this.contractData.state_address}} but in the component I drop the this from it. But I drop the this from it on all the other ones. I even tried with this.. It is weird. I was wondering if this is just my code or a normal thing for this not to work.

Comment: Could you please add html that you use for this form?

Comment: I updated my code. I tried to remove some of the extra stuff to make it easier on your eyes. Thank you for your help! Rember everything else works. Only state does not work. Which happens to be the combobox.

Comment: I cannot see `formControlName="state_address"` and any dropdown list in your html.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting text of option to `state`. You should set the `value` to `state` like that;

```
<option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{ state }}</option>
```